# How do I decrypt these file names on Android?

Tags: javascript, java, android

There are two types of url for file down on the server.

```
url1:  https://kimpus-storage.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/production/trade/files/%EA%B3%BC%EC%99%B8%EC%A0%84%EB%8B%A8%EC%A7%807-1578706405717.hwp?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJMWW26G6GWEQSXRQ%2F20200310%2Fap-northeast-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200310T002439Z&X-Amz-Expires=60&X-Amz-Signature=67e9785a85975e0134f7d343b647dd831c683b9937f69f83d88b5246bd50860e&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host

fileName: %EA%B3%BC%EC%99%B8%EC%A0%84%EB%8B%A8%EC%A7%807-1578706405717.hwp


url2: :https://kimpus-storage.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/production/trade/files/7849416f124907764a4eccaa410118-1542246838729-06822?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJMWW26G6GWEQSXRQ%2F20200310%2Fap-northeast-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200310T002358Z&X-Amz-Expires=60&X-Amz-Signature=d69857227953b01b02dcaa1a78204cde1ad24438154a9d13c2f151faf1b06eb2&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host

fileName2: 7849416f124907764a4eccaa410118-1542246838729-06822
```

First of all, there's a 60 second limit on downtime, so it won't work.

And both worked well in Chrome Browser.

The problem is I couldn't get a file extension when I downloaded the second file using the DownloadManager class on the Android app.

```
 String fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(url,null,null);

 android.app.DownloadManager downloadmanager = (android.app.DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                android.app.DownloadManager.Request request = new android.app.DownloadManager.Request(uri);
                request.setTitle(fileName);
                request.setDescription("Downloading");
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);
                request.setDestinationUri(Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/" +fileName));
```

Can I have a hint? JavaScript code is good, too.

Comment: A hint? You make us sound like a video game, or a quiz 

Comment: Instead of attempting to use a file extension, rely on the **mime-type** from the response with [`DownloadManager.getMimeTypeForDownloadedFile(long)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager#getMimeTypeForDownloadedFile(long))